# What is the difference between !python --version and sys.version for Google Colab?

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory, version, miniconda

I tried to install miniconda on Google Colab with different version of Python. But I cannot figure out why `!python --version` will be changed to 3.6.0 and `sys.version` stays the same as the default Python version from Google Colab. I ran the same codes on Kaggle Notebook. Kaggle will always return the same Python version number. Can anyone explain to me?

Here are the codes I ran on Google Colab.

The below 3 lines of codes will return Python 3.8.10 twice.

```
import sys
!python --version
print('\npython:', sys.version)
```

But after I installed miniconda with python 3.6 by the following 4 lines of codes, the above 3 lines of codes will return Python 3.6.0 and python 3.8.10.

```
%env PYTHONPATH=
! wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
! chmod +x Miniconda3-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
! bash ./Miniconda3-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local/
```

I suppose miniconda cannot change the Python version of Google Colab but it seems like miniconda did do some changes. Or, I did not understand the meaning of `!python --version` correctly?

Comment: so it means `!python --version` returns miniconda's python version number even I did not active conda on Colab? I ran the 3 blocks of codes all in different cells so I am confused.

Comment: Here I provide you the [Colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EXz26d8bpOZZ_2Rfkp0hmx3Yi6p9kuaq?usp=sharing) for reference.

Comment: One solution that makes sense is to install the conda that uses the same version of python as colab (in this case, 3.8). For example from here: [https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/) you would choose Miniconda3-py38_22.11.1-1-Linux-x86_64.sh. (By the way, I also suggest you to remove the google drive mounting from your example code - it has nothing to do with the question). And once you have installed conda, you need to add its site-packages to your sys.path, as described here: https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522

Comment: Also some useful example here (and note that once again, it is up to you to install a version of miniconda or conda that matches your colab python version): https://mri.sbollmann.net/index.php/2022/01/31/combining-conda-and-google-colab/

Comment: Thanks for many helpful references. I intend to install a python 3.6 minicoda because I need the environment to run some codes. I tried to downgrade the python on Colab before but somehow the kernel always broke down after I installed tensorflow on Colab. That is why I asked this question and try to find out how I can work with Colab.